# How to use Nokogiri to find all class elements in a webpage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse a webpage.

I'm able to succefully get the 1st bookTitle class element, but I'm trying to get all of the titles in an array.

But I'm struggling to get all the other elements. What's the best way to get them all?

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("https://www.goodreads.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=barack+obama&search_type=books&search%5Bfield%5D=author"))


puts doc.at_css('.bookTitle').content
# returns Dreams from My Father: A Story of Race and Inheritance

puts doc.xpath('//*[@class="bookTitle"]').size;
# returns 20, which is correct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`at_css` (or just `at`) returns first matched element (`Nokogiri::XML::Element`)

You need `css` method. It returns collection of matched elements (`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`)

```rb
doc.css('.bookTitle')
```

Probably you need to map through such collection

```rb
doc.css('.bookTitle').lazy.map(&:text).map(&:strip).to_a
```